# Flutter LockTask

Tags: android, flutter

I want to lockdown a flutter applicatio  with the android locktask. I tried several approaches but the setLockTaskPackages method doesn't seem to do anything. At first I tried to call the method in the onCreate function of the MainActivity. Then I tried to call it over a method channel but both approaches didn't work. Here is my onCreate funtion with method channel:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this);

        mDevicePolicyManager = (DevicePolicyManager) this.getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
        mAdminName = new ComponentName(this, Receiver_Admin.class);

        new MethodChannel(getFlutterView(), "com.packagename/kiosk").setMethodCallHandler(
                new MethodCallHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void onMethodCall(MethodCall call, Result result) {
                        mDevicePolicyManager.setLockTaskPackages(
                                mAdminName, 
                                new String[]{"com.packagename"}
                                );
                        result.success(null);
                    }
                }
        );
    }
```

My AndroidMainifest.xml:

```
        <receiver
                android:name=".receiver.Receiver_Admin"
                android:label="Sehne"
                android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN">
            <meta-data
                    android:name="android.app.device_admin"
                    android:resource="@xml/device_admin" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- This keeps the window background of the activity showing
                 until Flutter renders its first frame. It can be removed if
                 there is no splash screen (such as the default splash screen
                 defined in @style/LaunchTheme). -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.app.android.SplashScreenUntilFirstFrame"
                android:value="true" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Any ideas why nothing happens?

Thanks in advance

Comment: were you able to solve this?

Comment: I forgot to call the `startLockTask()` method. Now everything works.

Comment: where did you added startLockTask() ?